# How to implement code to find out Maximum Sum Subarray in FORWARD DP style?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have tried this recurrence relation:

```
`F(n) =  F(n+1)+ar[i] if it is +ve`
`     =  0 otherwise`
```

But I am getting wrong answer, I understand why is this giving me wrong after debugging, but I can't find the right solution. Could someone help me out?

Problem Statement:
Given an array A, return the the

```
max{sum(any subarray of A)}
```

Now if I traverse the array A, then each element will either be part of the solution already found or it will start a new solution.
A DP solution for this will be

```
def max_subarray(A):
   max_ending_here = max_so_far = 0
   for x in A:
      max_ending_here = max(0, max_ending_here + x)
      max_so_far = max(max_so_far, max_ending_here)
   return max_so_far
```

Now the problem is that I can't build the recurrence relation for the same.

Comment: What is Forward DP Style?

Comment: What is the "wrong answer?" Give us the failing test case. Otherwise, this is off topic: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers`

Comment: In your relation `F(n) =  F(n+1)+ar[i]` it is not clear what `i` means.

Comment: Visit this page for Forward Style DP, an excellent article on topcoder https://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=700080&start=0&mc=8

Comment: 'ar[i]' represents the current element of array 'ar'

Comment: The current element 'ar[i]' can either extend the old sum by adding itself to it, or it can start a new sum.

Comment: Please include a description of the Maximum Subarray Problem in the question and a more dedailed explanation of the recurrence relation.